# WWW-Authenticate schemes for OpenID Connect

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm writing my own codes for the OpenID Connect protocol.  Basically, I intend to write my own provider and related stuff on Google App Engine's platform using Jersey and Google's datastore via Objectify library.

I'm in the middle of implementing the (access/refresh) token endpoint and there's this client authentication that I need to take care of.  I'm just wondering if there are preset authentication schemes' keywords that I could send if in case the client did not have `client_secret_basic` set during the registration process (or whatever's set in the datastore entry.)

For a failed client authentication with the following methods, the scheme is used as response in the WWW-Authenticate header (401):

- `client_secret_basic`: `Basic`,
- `client_secret_post`: ???,
- `client_secret_jwt`: ???,
- `private_key_jwt`: ???,
- `none`: obviously none.

I've looked at some open source implementations, [nimbus](https://bitbucket.org/connect2id/oauth-2.0-sdk-with-openid-connect-extensions)' and [OAuth-Apis](https://github.com/OAuth-Apis/apis)', but they don't seem to handle this minor issue (they only respond with the generic error response defined in [OAuth2 rfc6749#section-5.2.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2))

If there are no predefined keywords, then I suppose I'll have to make up my own.  But it would be great if they exist.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question.  Is it that you went to send some extra information along w/ the 401.  If so then it's a function of the RP (Relying Party)  software you are using on your web server to return errors.  Also in the case of OpenIDC/Oauth2 the client is not the browser, it's the RP software on your server, and the "client authentication" is between your RP and your OP, not the Web Browser/End User and your RP.  The Web Browser should not know anything about the relationship between your RP and your OP and how they authenticate, that could provide an attack vector.

Comment: Yes, I want to send extra information in the WWW-Authenticate header along with the 401 response (and json error=invalid_client.)  No, my client is not the browser, I'm aware of that.  I don't think it's originally the function of the RP to send such errors, probably the RP relays it to the browser or whatever user-agent if that's what you mean, but the RP should initially get this error from the OP via the token endpoint in a failed RP (client) authentication response.

Comment: I'm using phpOIDC for my OP, and mod_auth_openidc for my RP. It allows for configuration on the OP of the token enpoint auth method per client_id. It looks up the method based on the client_assertion_type parameter and/or the types of algorithms.  I notice in the code for the OP there's a little bit that's commented out that says "Not sure why this is needed, not part of the spec".  It throws an error that says mismatched token endpoint auth type and shows the requested value and the value registered on the OP, i.e. client_secret_basic != client_secret_post. I think the answer is roll your own

Comment: @Severun Haha, thanks for the digging... I suppose I should just prefix them schemes with `OAuth2-*`.  I think I'll go with `OAuth2-Post`, `OAuth2-JWT`, etc. as they were initially introduced in OAuth2 anyways.  What you found in phpOIDC is pretty much what's implemented in OAuth2-apis and nimbus.

Answer (score 0):

The [authoritative list](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml) for these is at IANA. There, you can find these handfuls:

- Basic
- Bearer
- Digest
- HOBA
- Mutual
- Negotiate
- OAuth
- SCRAM-SHA1
- SCRAM-SHA-256
- vapid

Which of these is `client_secret_post`, `client_secret_jwt` and `private_key_jwt`? None. You'll need to map those to one from the registered list above or return your own values. Better yet, you can submit a draft to the OAuth working group or the OpenID Foundation to get the above IANA registry updated with something that makes sense for these missing cases. Then, we can all interop :-)